# showing the information with mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an application that lets the user place an order from the menu. My problem is When the user hovers the mouse over one of the images in the menu, another image should be displayed with the description and price of the item. The id attribute of each image identifies the image to be displayed when it’s rolled over. I tired to manged the first image to flip and show the description and price but the problem is when you click on the first image  it does not show the price on the order box and the image is not showing either

```js
$(function(){
  
  //declare prices and varaibles
  var item1 = $("#item1");
  item1.val(7.99);
  
  var item2 = $("#item2");
  item2.val(1.99);
  
  var item3 = $("#item3");
  item3.val(9.99);
  
  var item4 = $("#item4");
  item4.val(12.99);
  
  var item5 = $("#item5");
  item5.val(17.99);
  
  var item6 = $("#item6");
  item6.val(3.99);
 
  var Total = $("#Total");
  var Amount = 0; 
 
  //onclick
  var item = $(".item");
  var txtArea = $("#txtArea");
  var orderList = "";
  
  //Events
  item.click(function(event){
    
    Amount+=parseFloat($(event.target).val());
    orderList+=parseFloat($(event.target).val())+"$ -"+event.target.id  +"\n";
    
    txtArea.val(orderList);
    Total.html("Total: "+Amount.toFixed(2)+"$");
    
   
  });
  
  //Events
  item.hover(function(){
   $(event.target).text($(event.target).val()+"$");
    $(event.target).addClass("dark");
    
  }, function(){
     $(event.target).text("");
    $(event.target).removeClass("dark"); 
});
    
    
  //Clear Button
  var ClearOrder = $("#ClearOrder");
  //Events
  ClearOrder.click(function(){
    
    Amount = 0;
    Total.html("Total: "+Amount.toFixed(2));
    orderList ="";
    txtArea.val(orderList);
  });
    
   
 
            
       
            
 
  
  
  
  
  
  

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: "san-serif";
}

body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  
}

.Outside-Container{
  margin:10px;
  position:absolute;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:5%;
  width:60%;
  height:auto;
  left:20%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
  left:15%;
  overflow:hidden;
 
 
}

.top-logo-holder{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.logo-img{
    width: 31%; 
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.line{
  
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background:teal;
  border-radius:25%;
}

.main-section{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
}

.row1{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row2{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition:0.8s;
}

.item{
  width:300px;
  height:17vh;
  background:pink;
  margin:5px;
  color:#fff;
  transition:0.3s;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(1){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/2yCtXwNn/img1.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
 
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(2){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/vTXKRVGk/img2.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
.row1 .item:nth-child(3){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/J7QvH9jx/img3.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(1){
  background:url("[img4.jpg](https://postimg.cc/hh6pg86y)");
  background-size:cover;
}
.row2 .item:nth-child(2){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
.row2 .item:nth-child(3){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}


#txtArea{
  width:60%;
  height:150px;
}

.last-footer-line{
  
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.dark{
  filter:brightness(0.7);
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 5em;
}


 .flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>


<head>
 

<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="Outside-Container">
  <div class = "container">
   
   
   
   
    <div class="top-logo-holder">
     
       <img src ="https://i.postimg.cc/pL36txtW/logo.png" class="logo-img"/>
     
  <div class="line"></div>
     
  </div>  
   
    <div class="main-section">
      <div class ="row1">
        
        <div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <div class="flip"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>Coffee</h1>
      <h1>7.22$</h1>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
         <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
      </div>
     
       <div class ="row2">
        <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item6"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      <p>Your Order:</p>
      <textarea name="message" id="txtArea"></textarea>
       <p id="Total">Total: </p>
    </div>  
   
   
    <div class="last-footer-line">
      <button id="PlaceOrder">Place Order</button>
       <button id="ClearOrder">Clear Order</button>
      <div>
     
     
    </div>
   
   
   
   
</div>
</div>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
</body>
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  //declare prices and varaibles
  var item1 = $("#item1");
  item1.val(7.99);

  var item2 = $("#item2");
  item2.val(1.99);

  var item3 = $("#item3");
  item3.val(9.99);

  var item4 = $("#item4");
  item4.val(12.99);

  var item5 = $("#item5");
  item5.val(17.99);

  var item6 = $("#item6");
  item6.val(3.99);

  var Total = $("#Total");
  var Amount = 0;

  //onclick
  var item = $(".item");
  var txtArea = $("#txtArea");
  var orderList = "";

  //Events

  $('.flip-card-back').click(function() {
    var price = $('.flip-card-back .Item1_price').text().slice(0, -1);

    Amount += parseFloat(price);
    orderList += parseFloat(price) + "$ -item1 \n";

    txtArea.val(orderList);
    Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2) + "$");


  });
  item.click(function(event) {

    Amount += parseFloat($(event.target).val());
    orderList += parseFloat($(event.target).val()) + "$ -" + event.target.id + "\n";

    txtArea.val(orderList);
    Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2) + "$");


  });

  //Events
  item.hover(function() {
    $(event.target).text($(event.target).val() + "$");
    $(event.target).addClass("dark");

  }, function() {
    $(event.target).text("");
    $(event.target).removeClass("dark");
  });


  //Clear Button
  var ClearOrder = $("#ClearOrder");
  //Events
  ClearOrder.click(function() {

    Amount = 0;
    Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2));
    orderList = "";
    txtArea.val(orderList);
  });


























})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "san-serif";
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.Outside-Container {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  left: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  left: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-logo-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.logo-img {
  width: 31%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 17vh;
  background: pink;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/2yCtXwNn/img1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vTXKRVGk/img2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/J7QvH9jx/img3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: url("[img4.jpg](https://postimg.cc/hh6pg86y)");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#txtArea {
  width: 60%;
  height: 150px;
}

.last-footer-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dark {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="js/tabs.js"></script>


<head>


  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Outside-Container">
    <div class="container">




      <div class="top-logo-holder">

        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pL36txtW/logo.png" class="logo-img" />

        <div class="line"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="main-section">
        <div class="row1">

          <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <div class="flip"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>Coffee</h1>
                <h1 class='Item1_price'>7.22$</h1>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row2">
          <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>Your Order:</p>
        <textarea name="message" id="txtArea"></textarea>
        <p id="Total">Total: </p>
      </div>


      <div class="last-footer-line">
        <button id="PlaceOrder">Place Order</button>
        <button id="ClearOrder">Clear Order</button>
        <div>


        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is this what you want , or need more modifications

Comment: also why first item big without image like others

Comment: i edited first answer also  check both to see what is best for you , both will work , but first is more organized

Answer (score 0):

i added rotate card on hover for any item & set item1 as first item

`item.mouseleave(function() {
    $('.flip-card-inner').removeClass('flipcard');
  });
$('.flip-card-inner').addClass('flipcard');`

added css class`.flipcard {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}`

also added img & price onhover event using`$('.flip-card-back').html($(event.target).val()+'$');
    $('.flip-card-back').css('background', $(event.target).css('background'));`

.

is this what you want

```js
$(function() {

  //declare prices and varaibles
  var item1 = $("#item1");
  item1.val(7.99);

  var item2 = $("#item2");
  item2.val(1.99);

  var item3 = $("#item3");
  item3.val(9.99);

  var item4 = $("#item4");
  item4.val(12.99);

  var item5 = $("#item5");
  item5.val(17.99);

  var item6 = $("#item6");
  item6.val(3.99);

  var Total = $("#Total");
  var Amount = 0;

  //onclick
  var item = $(".item");
  var txtArea = $("#txtArea");
  var orderList = "";

  //Events
  item.hover(function(event) {
    $('.flip-card-back').html($(event.target).val() + '$');
    $('.flip-card-back').css('background', $(event.target).css('background'));
    $('.flip-card-inner').addClass('flipcard');
  }, function() {
    $('.flip-card-inner').removeClass('flipcard');
  });

  item.click(function(event) {
    Amount += parseFloat($(event.target).val());
    orderList += parseFloat($(event.target).val()) + "$ -" + event.target.id + "\n";

    txtArea.val(orderList);
    Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2) + "$");
  });

  //Events
  item.hover(function() {
    $(event.target).text($(event.target).val() + "$");
    $(event.target).addClass("dark");

  }, function() {
    $(event.target).text("");
    $(event.target).removeClass("dark");
  });


  //Clear Button
  var ClearOrder = $("#ClearOrder");
  //Events
  ClearOrder.click(function() {

    Amount = 0;
    Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2));
    orderList = "";
    txtArea.val(orderList);
  });


























})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "san-serif";
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.Outside-Container {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  left: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  left: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-logo-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.logo-img {
  width: 31%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 17vh;
  background: pink;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/2yCtXwNn/img1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vTXKRVGk/img2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/J7QvH9jx/img3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(1) {
  background: url("https://www.gourmesso.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/03/Tiramisu-Coffee-in-a-Glass-Recipe-Italian-dessert-speciality.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: url("http://hopecoffeeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Grid-home-item-show-img.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#txtArea {
  width: 60%;
  height: 150px;
}

.last-footer-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dark {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipcard {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="js/tabs.js"></script>


<head>


  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Outside-Container">
    <div class="container">




      <div class="top-logo-holder">

        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pL36txtW/logo.png" class="logo-img" />

        <div class="line"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="main-section">

        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
              <div class="flip"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
              <h1></h1>
              <h1></h1>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row1">

          <div class="item" id="item1"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row2">
          <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
          <div class="item" id="item6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>Your Order:</p>
        <textarea name="message" id="txtArea"></textarea>
        <p id="Total">Total: </p>
      </div>


      <div class="last-footer-line">
        <button id="PlaceOrder">Place Order</button>
        <button id="ClearOrder">Clear Order</button>
        <div>


        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: kanyan thank you for taking your time and helping me but unfortunately your code does not work :(

Comment: what do you mean run the snippet , tell me what exactly doesn't work

Comment: click on the cup images

Comment: try to click on the first box and check if anything is showing on your order box

Comment: o sorry u miss understand my friend , this is not how suppose to work

Comment: lets use the second box as an example .lets when user hover on the second box that box has to flip and show the name and the price for that box and if the client click on that box it has show the price on the your order box on the bottom

Comment: so you don't want the rotating element to view other items  ,  why not add the coffee$7.22 item   as a separate  item

Comment: im trying to create this https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/index-html-tuxedo-cat-coffee-menu-click-item-add-order-order-css-body-font-family-verdana--q24462112